# db2 command not found in unix

Tags: unix, db2

I am trying to execute a simple db2 command in Linux command prompt. but Linux command prompt is not recognizing the command it is giving - bash db2 command not found. but db2 is installed in the Linux machine.

*command I am trying to execute from Linux command line processor is* **db2 "create database smaple"**

*Error I am getting is below* **"If db2 in not a typo you can run the following command to lookup the package that contains the binary" command-not-found db2 -bash: db2: command not found"**

Is this because of environment variable problem ?? or there is only one instance of db2 ie db2inst1 is running in the machine.my user name in **appsusr** and db2 instance name is **db2inst1** are different is this causing problem?? and I am not having super user access.Is this is causing any problem?? do I need super user access is required ??

Comment: Sounds like you need to modify your `PATH` environment variable so it contains the directory where `db2` was installed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just type, **echo $PATH** in your command prompt , where you can see all the exported paths in your system.

If the db2 path is not found in your environment variable list, then do the following.

export PATH=$PATH:/opt/IBM/db2/V10.1/bin

and then press enter. 
 I hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: I'm surprised this works, since you should be setting your environment variables via the `db2profile` script (see my answer below)

Answer (score 4):

On Linux and UNIX DB2 platforms, the proper way to set your environment variables to run DB2 commands is to source the `sqllib/db2profile` script belonging to the local DB2 instance owner. That will set not only your `PATH` but also other important variables that DB2 requires.

In your case, the instance is owned by the `db2inst1` user, so your login startup file or batch script should run this command:

`. ~db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile`

The leading dot is necessary to set the variables in your current shell process, not the sub-process that quickly vanishes after db2profile finishes.

Comment: profiles don't run sometimes causing this the PATH variable to not get modified...

Comment: If your profile doesn't run automatically during login, you will need to source db2profile yourself. Either way, you shouldn't need to modify your PATH variable to use DB2 because that's part of what the db2profile command does.

Comment: What is the `~` before the `db2inst1` ?

Comment: @gfan, the `~` is a shortcut in Linux and UNIX that refers to the user's home directory, so `~db2inst1` means the home directory of the `db2inst1` user, but `~` or `~/` without a username means your home directory.

Answer (score 2):

It's more than likely that, if DB2 is installed, it's simply not in your path.

Your path should contain something like:

```
/opt/IBM/db2/V10.1/bin
```

which is where the executables live (depending on which version you're running).

Changing your path will probably entail changes to one of the startup files, such as `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.

Comment: where I need to see path is present or not.In my .bashrc only this entry there 
test -s ~/.alias && . ~/.alias || true

Comment: What is that DB2 version?

Comment: hey thanks Shivaraj Bhat. Thanks for every one's reply. Finally after setting db2 environmental variable it is now working. I set updated env variable by following command export PATH=$PATH:export PATH=$PATH:/opt/IBM/db2/V10.1/bin it is working.

Comment: @ChandanDN Hi Chandan, please upvote the answer if it found useful by any means.. :)