# How to increase db2 transaction log size in docker container

Tags: linux, docker, db2, transaction-log

i have a db2 luw running in a docker container. How can I increase the increase transaction log size of it. 
I tried to run "db2 connect to UEQ1D" in the docker Container cli. But docker gives the Respond: command not found. Do I need to somehow install db2cmd or so on the container or how can I run db2 commands on docker. Or is there a simpler way or so?

Appreciate your help

Comment: Do you know how to increase it in general?

Comment: I found some commands online but cant run them in the docker Container

Comment: Then add what you already know and what you tried. Is it that access to the container is missing or you don't know to to configure the logsize

Comment: oki do you know what I mean ;D

Comment: Duplicate of [db2 command not found in unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27898194/db2-command-not-found-in-unix)